# ElasticSearch with AngularJS does not return data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, elasticsearch

I am developing an data visualization application where data is retrieved from the elastic search. This is the first time am retrieving data from elastic search using angular.

I followed this sample to retrieve the data [`Getting Started with elasticsearch and AngularJS`](http://www.fullscale.co/blog/2013/02/28/getting_started_with_elasticsearch_and_AngularJS_searching.html), here is my code,

**App.Js**

```
var routerApp = angular.module('DuoDiginRt',  ['ui.bootstrap','ngRoute', 'elasticjs.service']);

routerApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, ejsResource) {
         var ejs = ejsResource('http://localhost:9200');
          var index = 'calldetails';    
         var statusRequest = ejs.Request()
        .indices(index)
        .types('typecalldetails');
}
```

**My data:**

[image]

Comment: Where is the problem? What doesn't work? In the tutorial link you posted everything is documented. As you initialized your request, you can now perform a search.

Comment: As Himmet mentioned above, please post a plunkr or code demo so we can see what you have, and let us know what the error is! We can't fix what we don't know is broken.

Comment: @HimmetAvsar Problem is i dont see any data in statusRequest